# ASP.Net Treeview check node exists

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, treeview

I am working with ASP.Net Treeview and I need to check the existence of a node before adding a new node so that I don't have a duplication (which is what I am getting at the moment because of the state of the data.

I have tried `TreeView1.FindNode(newNode.Text)` which does get me a value if the nodes exists, but when trying to run a if statement on it to check its not nothing, or if it exists visual studio gives me an error to advise that cannot convert string to Boolean.

When trying

```
If Convert.ToBoolean(TreeView1.FindNode(node.Id)) = Nothing Then
                exists = False
            Else
                exists = True
End If
```

this always returns false even if it is not nothing

when trying

```
If TreeView1.FindNode(node.Id) = Nothing Then
                exists = False
            Else
                exists = True
End If`
```

this is where I get the error.

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I think this post describes a solution to your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097029/c-sharp-treeview-checking-if-node-exists Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `TreeView1.FindNode` returns `TreeNode` and you are trying to convert that to a boolean which will never work.  This should work:-

```
If TreeView1.FindNode(node.Id) Is Nothing Then
      exists = False
Else
      exists = True
End If
```

**Update:**

You can also use a little bit of LINQ to find existance. I personally like this approach:-

```
Dim exist As Boolean = TreeView1.Nodes.OfType(Of TreeNode)() _
                                      .Any(Function(x) x.Value = node.Id)
```

Comment: I realized this just before seeing your answer... anyone can feel free to mark me down for my utter stupidity

Comment: @SimonPrice - Hey its not stupidity, these things happens in coding world :) I have added one more approach by which we can find the existence of a treenode.

Comment: Thank you, I am able to find the parent with the initial attempt but I'm unable to find specific child nodes now so hopefully this new bit of code will help me too.